# Debugging A XamlParseException

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xamlparseexception

I am being driven quietly mad by a XamlParseException and would welcome some thoughts from those of you more familiar with this type of exception.

The message that comes up is as follows:

'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Tracker.UsersControlViewModel' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '11' and line position '14'.

If I go on to examine the inner exception it tells me;

{"Value cannot be null.Parameter name: meth"} which is of type System.ArguementNullException.

What frustrates me with this is that the viewmodel where this is thrown has a simple constructor that takes no parameters and nothing that it in turn calls has any parameters, al least not that I can see from trying to follow this through.

I freely admit that wpf is a whole new ball game to me, which is probably why I'm missing something obvious so if any of you could throw some suggestions as to where to look I'd welcome them.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: look for something called "meth" in your code. That's null. Fix it.